# Android CardView Error

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to implement the CardView design in my code; however, I get the error that states TextView and RelativeLayout are not allowed here.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            style="@style/ItemBackground">

        <TextView android:text="@string/weather"
            android:id="@+id/weather_header"
            style="@style/ItemHeader" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/weather_header"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you put the `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'` in your gradle?

Comment: yes, i have compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'

Comment: try removing the style from the relative and textview and see if it works.

Comment: i tried removing them and i still get the same error

Comment: @00_td_00 can you paste the full error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <TextView android:text="weather"
            android:id="@+id/weather_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="ABCDEF"
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/weather_header"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

It works now. I don't notice any error to this layout
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE8qk.png
What is for about the issue of textview. You lost to add layout height and width.